# Why doesn't my nav burger show the block when i click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, hamburger-menu

I've been struggling with this problem the last few days and it's so frustrating. I can't figure out why my burger won't show anything when i click on it. The animation of the burger does work tho. I know it's a lot of code, but can someone help me figure this problem out?

When you click on the burger (mobile navbar), the block with the nav-links won't show. I've wrote my code a couples of times and i still don't see the problem..

```
 <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="gym.html">Gym's</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-logo">
            <img src="img/logo-white.png">        
        </div>

        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="nieuw.html">Nieuw?</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    min-height: 8vh;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100%;
}

nav .nav-logo {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.nav-links li {
    margin: 0px 5vh;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--orange-color);
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%)
}

.current {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: -30px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: var(--black-color);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
}

<script>
        const navSlide = () => {
        const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
        const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
        const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    
        burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Toggle Nav
            nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    
            // Animate Links
            navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
                if(link.style.animation){
                    link.style.animation = ''
                } else {
                    link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
                }
            });
            // Burger animation
            burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
        });
    }
    
    navSlide();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but the block is being showed outside the browser window.

Try to the delete from class "nav-links" below declaration:

```
transform: translateX(100%);
```

Then you will see your block.